# pyglet on_key_press Error: 'key' not defined

Tags: opengl, event-handling, pyglet

I'm using pyglet and trying to handle keyPress events with the on_key_press method. I keep getting the same error when defining events for specific symbols like key.UP:

```
NameError: global name 'key' is not defined
```

based on the examples I've seen in the pyglet documentation, no prior definition of key is necessary. Am I mistaken or is there something else I'm missing?

here's the code I'm using for the event handler

```
@window.event
def on_key_press(symbol, modifier):
    if symbol == key.UP:
        data.rx -= 2
        draw()
    elif symbol == key.DOWN:
        data.rx += 2
        draw()
    elif symbol == key.SPACE:
        close()
```

Comment: I got bitten by this myself. The pyglet examples often leave out bits of code on the mistaken assumption that it's so obvious you'll work it out yourself. You do need to import pyglet.window.key (and probably pyglet.window.mouse)

Comment: That was it! Thanks! with that tip i was able to find the pertinent page in the pyglet documentation. Just for the record the syntax that worked is 'from pyglet.window import key'

Comment: @HughFisher Could i ask you to write 3-4 lines as an answer so this question doesn't show up in the unanswered section of Pyglet, thank you!